# Facebook Authentication for user with multiple iOS devices (Ruby On Rails and iOS SDK)?

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ios6, ios7

Currently my iOS app facebook atuhtentication does not work for users that have two iOS devices.

It works only when the user has one iOS device. The app uses the iOS SDK. (Not the Facebook SDK)

On the server side I use a rails app. The rails app receives a facebook token from the iOS app, and it uses the token to fetch the user email and profile picture.

```
  @graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(facebook_token)
  profile = @graph.get_object("me")
  profile_picture = @graph.get_picture("me")
```

Koala responds with the following error:

```
"Koala::Facebook::AuthenticationError: type: OAuthException, code: 190, error_subcode: 460, 
message: Error validating access token: Session does not match current stored session. This 
may be because the user changed the password since the time the session was created or 
Facebook has changed the session for security reasons. [HTTP 400]"
```

I would like to know how to solve this issue and allow facebook authentication for users with more than one iOS device?

Thanks in advance.

**SOLUTION**
For this case the solution consited in handling the authenticaiton via the facebook device, instead of via the rails app.

Also it is useful to have a server based facebook authentication cache. Per Facebook documentation recommendation:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/login-tutorial/#tokencache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

For this case the solution consited in handling the authenticaiton via the facebook device, instead of via the rails app.

Also it is useful to have a server based facebook authentication cache. Per Facebook documentation recommendation:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/login-tutorial/#tokencache